# App engine authentication

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

I am new to appengine. I will write application which consist of two parts.

1) Core written in app engine with **REST** interface for clients.
2) Client application written in J2EE on my other (not appengine) server. But here, client may use any other technology (android, swing etc.)

I dont know, how to handle authentication of users in this schema. I think that I am in the middle between standard login and installed applications.

The simplest solution that occured to me, that the client will request username+password, pass it to appengine application via *https* and it will authenticate.

But dont know how to synchronized the login with client app, because it will need also data from google applications...

Is there any solution or pre-prepared facility in Java how to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/) for this; client login or using username+password is not a good way to do this, and informed users will be -- or SHOULD be -- hesitant to give away their passwords. There is a page for using [OAuth within AppEngine applications written in Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview.html) which may be of use. There is also some support for Oauth in the [GData client library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/). The [OAuth in the Google Data Protocol Client Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html) document may help you to understand how to use those features.